# Spring Security 3.1 & Active Directory - how to set up config for users and groups

Tags: xml, active-directory, ldap

I have not been able to find anything relating to what I want to achieve

I have a web system that is using Spring Secuirty 3.1 that needs to link users from an Active Directory. For my dev, I was just storing them in the spring-security.xml file. This was fine, but for production, I need to have the users linked from Active Directory. I have this working now so I can log in ect, so this isn't the issue. The issue I have is, in my local dev work, I had users and "groups", i.e. ROLE_USER and ROLE_ADMIN.

In Active directory, there are two groups that map on to these names. I need to do the URL intercept-url based on these role types, but I dont know how to do this for active directory.

This is my local dev version that hard codes the users in the authentication-provider. This needs to be forr active directory:

```
<http auto-config="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/test/*" access="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN"  />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="ROLE_ADMIN"  />
    <intercept-url pattern="/list*" access="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" 
            default-target-url="/home" 
            authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/logout" />
    <session-management invalid-session-url="/login">
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"/>
    </session-management>       
</http> 

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="test" password="test" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

BUT, what I need to do is replace this with active directory based authentication-manager.

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider"/>
</authentication-manager>
```

I know the users are in this directory for AD:

OU=Users,OU=Z3,DC=i1,DC=z12,DC=r1,DC=net

and the groups are in:

OU=Groups,OU=Z3,DC=i1,DC=z12,DC=r1,DC=net

The key attribute in Active Directory that is used to log in is 'SAM-Account-Name'

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Spring Security Reference!

[Chapter 19.5 Active Directory Authentication](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ldap.html)